# How is schema from Schema-Registry is propagated over Replicator

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

How do schemas from Confluent Schema-Registry get propagated by Confluent-Replicator to destination Kafka-Cluster and Schema-Registry?

Is each replicated message schema contained in it or are schemas replicated somehow separately through a separate topic?

I didn't see any configuration possibilities in Confluent-Replicator regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking how the schema registry can be used in a multi data center environment. There's a pretty good doc on this https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/multidc.html

Replicator can be used to keep the schema registry data in sync on the backend as shown in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Schemas are not stored with the topic, only their ID's. And the `_schemas` topic is not replicated, only the ID's stored within the replicated topics.

On a high-level, if you use the `AvroConverter` with Replicator, it'll deserialize the message from the source cluster, optionally rename the topic as per the replicator configuration, then serialize the message and send the new subject name to the destination cluster + registry.

Otherwise, if you use the `ByteArrayConverter`, it will not inspect the message, and it just copies it along to the destination cluster with no registration.

A small optimization on the Avro way would be to only inspect that the message is Avro encoded on the first 5 bytes, as per the Schema Registry specification, then perform HTTP lookups to the source subject using Schema Registry REST API `GET /schemas/ids/:id`, again rename topic if needed to the destination cluster, and `POST` the schema there. A similar approach can work in any Consumer/Producer pair such as a MirrorMaker `MessageHandler` implementation.